# Keep footer at bottom of page, only appearing after scrolling

Tags: html, css, alignment, footer, sticky

I am attempting to have the footer of a webpage containing a number of images (and thus requiring lots of scrolling) appear only after the page has finished scrolling. Instead, the footer is appearing at the bottom of the page BEFORE any scrolling has occurred, and therefore ends up somewhere awkwardly in the middle of my page.

Relevant HTML:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="index.html" id="logo"> <h1>
        <div id="header_title">
            Title
        </div></h1> </a>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html" >About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="resume.html">Resume</a>
                </li>
                <li class="subNav">
                    <a class="selected" >Portfolio</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="writing_samples.html">Writing Samples</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="photoshop.html">Photoshop</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <section>
            <ul id="gallery">
                <li>
                    ... images would go here, normally there would be many <li> with content inside them; shortened here for simplicity
                </li>   
            </ul>
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer>
            <p>
                &copy; 2016 Name.
            </p>
        </footer>
</body>
```

And CSS:

```
    html {
    height: 100%;
    }

    body {
        font-family: 'Playfair Display', open sans;
        position: relative;
        height: 100%; 
    }


    footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both; /* cleared from influence of any other floats
     cleared on both left and right sides */
    padding-top: 50px;
    color: #000000;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: have you tried removing position: absolute; from the footer's css?

Comment: i reposted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

remove position: absolute; from the footer's css

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11500939)

Comment: @sebastianbrosch I apologize. I didn't see and still don't see any question from the post. The post presented a problem and I simply provided a solution. Furthermore, as per the author, my solution did work.

Comment: In my opinion this is a comment, because you only say "remove this!" - add a explanation and don't provide a low quality answer! - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

Having a position of 'absolute', your footer's position is not dependant on the content pushing it down.  It is only dependant on the parent div with a position of 'relative'.  In this case, your body tag.  If you give your footer a position of 'relative'(which is the default), it will be pushed down by your content like you want.